# Foreman and Configuration Manager/SCCM for deployment

Tags: windows, puppet, deployment, sccm, foreman

I recently have been made a Windows sysadmin in our place of work after many years as a client admin. For the past 5 I have been the lead on Configuration Manager/SCCM (up to the most recent current branch release) and am intimately familiar with it. All of our clients and servers are managed with SCCM.

Our Linux sysadmins have implemented and use Foreman for system deployment, and moving forward it is expected Foreman/Puppet will be used to maintain inventory of all systems in our data center. I was shown a demo (which was impressive) of a Windows machine being deployed with Foreman using a VMWare template. However, I am under the impression maintaining VMWare templates is much more manual than I want to see. I have already been told that after deployment of the VM the existing admins are doing things like applying updates and installing needed software. A Server 2016 image has not even been built yet. This is where SCCM comes in.

I am envisioning a Foreman workflow that boots the VM to SCCM/WDS PXE and then allows for a zero or light touch deployment. Is this a typical workflow with Foreman? This way we can maintain image building and deployment on SCCM but still use Foreman for everything else. I am wary of being someone who because I have a hammer in my toolbelt (SCCM) everything looks like a nail. I want to be open minded and put the best interests of the institution and my co-workers before any product loyalty.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at https://github.com/kireevco/wimaging, I believe this is the easiest way to deploy "bare metal" windows with foreman.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. That is what we have primarily been looking at but at the end of the day it is duplicating functionality in a lot of ways so I find it frustrating as an "SCCM guy."